# Strange results passing "date" input through JSON

Tags: javascript, php, html, json

I'm trying to send a date entered by a user on a form to my server backend (all data is sent in JSON format, as I'm working with JavaScript for a hybrid application). The result being sent to the server however is this:

On the application I enter the following date:

```
July 18, 1994
```

On the server, it receives the following input:

```
1994-07-18T05:00:00.000Z
```

I don't understand what's with the `T05:00:00.000Z` text that follows or understand what it's for, or how to get rid of it.

This request is being sent through the `$http` module in AngularJS. The `date` field is linked using `ng-model` to a date input on a form.

```
createRequest($http, "register", $scope.formData, function(data) {
    alert(JSON.strinfify(data));
});
```

Here is the createRequest method:

```
function createRequest($http, requestType, requestData, onResponse, onFailed) {
    console.log("Creating a request");
    requestData['request'] = requestType;
    requestData['version'] = applicationVersion;
    $http.post("file.php", requestData).success(function(data) {
        if(data.status == "mismatch") {
            forceUpdate();  
        } else if(data.status == "e_error") {
            alert(data.message);    
        } else if(data.status == "u_error") {
            onFailed();
        } else if(data.status == "success") {
            onResponse(data);
        } else {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        }
    });
}
```

Thanks in advance for any information.

Comment: I suspect the Javascript is converting the date into the *local* midnight at the start of that date, and I suspect your local time zone is 5 hours behind UTC. Of course, it would be easier to know what's going on if you would post the Javascript code...

Comment: The JavaScript code is literally just passing a forms value through an AJAX request through AngularJS's `$http`.   -- `$http.post('localhost', { date: date }).success(function(data) { alert(JSON.stringify(data)); });`

Comment: Well it's not passing "July 18, 1994" - so if that's the form's input, there's clearly a conversion going on somewhere. You should chase down where that happens. (Check what's happening at the network level too, to make sure it isn't a conversion on the server side - I doubt that it is though.)

Comment: The server currently doesn't do any logic but print out the date (in this case, as I'm trying to figure out how to get a regular date), JavaScript seems to (by default?) add the TimeZone to the end to a date input. Sending this over the network constantly is a bit pointless.

Comment: It's not adding the time zone. It's just converting the value into a UTC instant. But if you want to change it, do - you need to find out *exactly* where it's happening though.